# why is my 2d c array working only for values < 4?

Tags: c, parsing, segmentation-fault, multidimensional-array

i am new to c programming . i made a parser which gets a char array (a *command* which later should also have arguments) and should divide it into smaller arrays. From there i want to further analize each array on its own. There is probably a better way to solve this problem but i really just want to understand what is happening here.

when i run the debugger (yes i did run the debugger) it tells me there is a segmentation fault at this line.

```
commandArray[kk][ii - jj] = (char) input[ii];
```

this only happens after kk > 3 but runs well for all smaller numbers. Also the same problem occurs at kk >3 when i use different strings. with **kk == 4** and **(ii - jj) == 0**.

it occurs when i want to fill an 2d array with characters.

```
//fill each Array entry with a command (a command is just a string)
jj = 0;
kk = 0;
ii = 0;

while (ii != (int) strlen(input)) {

    commandArray[kk][ii - jj] = (char) input[ii];

    if ((char) input[ii] == ';') {
        commandArray[kk][ii - jj + 1] = '\0';
        jj = ii + 1;
        kk++;
    }
    ii++;
}
```

i am pretty sure that i have declared the 2d array correctly:

```
//allocate space for each command
commandArray = (char**) calloc(numberOfCommands, sizeof(char)); //create n char arrays
for (ii = 0; ii < numberOfCommands; ii++) {
    commandArray[ii] = (char*) calloc((lengthOfCommand[ii]), sizeof(char));
}
```

i dont know f you need further code so i have used pastebin to include my complete code (~100 lines)

the Main that calls my function:

http://pastebin.com/P9TfDUs7

the complete Parser.c file:

http://pastebin.com/WFvrLS1r

and the Parser.h:

```
#ifndef PARSER_H_
#define PARSER_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void command(char* commandArray);



#endif /* PARSER_H_ */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each command entry is a string of `char`s.  When you allocate the memory for those strings (correctly, I think) you get back pointers to the first `char` in each string.

So your array of commands is implemented as a list of *pointers*.  But when you allocated the memory for the list of pointers, you only allowed enough space for each pointer to fit in a `char`.  It is highly unlikely that a pointer value, which is essentially a memory location, will fit in a `char`.

Try changing your first `calloc` call so that the second parameter is `sizeof(char *)`.

If this is unclear, writing a tiny program to print out `sizeof(char)` and `sizeof(char *)` might help.